# Web Captcha Control Dont work in the host

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

I Wrote a Website that has a captcha that i got it from [Captcha for ASP.NET(Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8751/A-CAPTCHA-Server-Control-for-ASP-NET) 
it work perfectly in my localhost, but when i uploaded to host by Publishing Website, the image of captcha not shows

Answer (score 0):

[Register HTTPHandler in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

404 response is getting from this url for your site:

> http://shahriarfestival.com/CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=c36ac5cc-0874-4107-ab9f-d54feb0c9c7f

Kindly check `CaptchaImage.aspx` is present in your hosted application.

#### EDIT

> http://shahriarfestival.com/images/shadow.gif

This image is missing from your application.

Comment: this image is in http://shahriarfestival.com/shadow.gif and is not related to captcha

Comment: these are the issues find by looking your site. for details plz post your code. can't guess more now :)

Answer (score 0):

http://shahriarfestival.com/CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=c36ac5cc-0874-4107-ab9f-d54feb0c9c7f

This Code Is Not Work In local host too 
check Uploaded Files and Check Published Files And Directory

Comment: you dont have source files to test in local

Comment: wow - local and IIs Difrents 1 - Source(Data xml web config) or (concorent Visits)

Comment: you have Error in Url Page my Iranian Firend